# Why can't I reclaim my dynamically allocated memory using the "delete" keyword?

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

I have the following class:

```
class Patient {
public:
    Patient(int x);
    ~Patient();
private:
    int* RP;
};

Patient::Patient(int x) { RP = new int [x]; }
Patient::~Patient() { delete [] RP; }
```

I create an instance of this class on the stack as follows:

```
void f() { Patient p(10); }
```

Now, when `f()` returns, I get a "double free or corruption" error, which signals to me that something is attempted to be deleted more than once. But I don't understand why that would be so.  The space for the array is created on the heap, and just because the function from inside which the space was allocated returns, I wouldn't expect the space to be reclaimed.

I thought that if I allocate space on the heap (using the `new` keyword), then the only way to reclaim that space is to use the delete keyword. Help!

**As requested, here is the actual code (slightly abridged for brevity's sake)**

Here's the full class definition (split across a `.cpp` and `.h` file, but shown together):

```
class Patient {

public:
    Patient(int numDecisionEpochs);

    ~Patient();

    void recordRP(const int& age, const bool& t);
    void recordBiopsy(const int& age, const int& result);
    void recordPSA(const int& age, const double& level);
    void recordPSA(const int& age);
private:
    int* RP;
    int* Biopsy;
    double* PSA;
};

Patient::Patient(int numDecisionEpochs) {
    RP = new int [numDecisionEpochs];
    Biopsy = new int [numDecisionEpochs];
    PSA = new double [numDecisionEpochs];
}

Patient::~Patient() {
    delete[] RP;
}

void Patient::recordRP(const int& age, const bool& t) {
    if(t)
    RP[age-1] = 1;  // RP either yes (1) or no (0)
    else
    RP[age-1] = 0;
}

void Patient::recordBiopsy(const int& age, const int& result) {
    switch(result)
    {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        Biopsy[age-1]=result; // only permit results 0,1,2,3,4
        break;
    default:
        cerr << "Invalid biopsy result (" << result << ") at age " << age << "!\n";
    }
}

void Patient::recordPSA(const int& age, const double& level) {
    PSA[age-1] = level; // record PSA volume
}

void Patient::recordPSA(const int& age) {
    PSA[age-1] = -1; // symbol for no screening during epoch
}
```

Next, the function where the above class is used.  The following function is called directly from `main()` and passed a `Policy` object which is completely independent and separate from the `Patient` class:

```
void simulate1(Policy& P)
{
    // ...
    Patient patient(260);

    for(int idx=0; idx<(P.size); idx++)
    {
        while(state != 9) // while patient not dead
        {
                // ...
                patient.recordPSA(age,PSA);
                // ...
                patient.recordPSA(age);
                // ...
                patient.recordBiopsy(age,biopsyResult);
                // ...
                patient.recordRP(age,true);
                // ...
                patient.recordRP(age,false);
                // ...

        } // end patient (while loop)

    } // end sample (for loop)

} // end function
```

Comment: Your code runs fine: http://ideone.com/Gw2QM. And technically `delete` is not guaranteed to reclaim any space, it's possible you could have a `new` and `delete` implementation that just keep on allocating memory pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're violating the [rule-of-three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/636019) (or for C++11, the [rule-of-five](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4782757/636019)). You need a copy constructor and copy-assignment operator that does a deep copy of the pointer. Of course, since you don't track the size of the array you allocate, this isn't possible without introducing a second data member.

Comment: It's also possible that the most correct thing would be to disallow copying, i.e. add `private: Patient(const Patient&);` to the class definition.  Especially when it comes to objects manually handling pointers, unintentional copying can be just wrong.

Comment: @Steve : The most likely scenario, IMO, is that the OP should just be using `std::vector<int>` instead of `int*`. ;-]

Comment: What is "OP", ordinary person?

If I use std::vector<T> and the "reserve()" member function to pre-allocate space, should I expect to observe no difference in speed over the arrays and pointers method I'm using? (Assume that the code using the array or vector is the bottleneck.)

Comment: @synaptik : Original Poster, aka you. :-] And yes, once you implement proper copy/move semantics, if you use `reserve` properly there will be no perceptible difference between `std::vector<>` and raw C-arrays in release mode.

Comment: @ildjarn, I agree (and commented below) but remember that copying a vector is expensive and probably not what you want most of the time (hence my "disallow copying" suggestion).

Comment: @Steve : If the class should remain non-copyable, agreed. But if the class needs to make a deep copy either way, there's no remaining reason to not use `std::vector<>`.

Comment: In the code I posted above, where is the "copying" taking place?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but also consider using std::vector.

Comment: It's a perfectly valid suggestion since the author clearly isn't very experienced with C++.  One of the mistakes of learning C++ is to treat it like C and then learn how to do classes (so you manage the memory for a list of integers yourself).  This isn't a direct answer but I think in C++ this kind of answer should be encouraged as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough rep to just make a comment.  I can only answer.

Comment: Yes, I do use vectors.  But this code is at the center of a simulation which is run millions and millions of times (embedded in a heuristic optimization), and so I only used arrays because some people have told me they're slightly faster (though others tell me otherwise, especially for newer C++ implementation).

Comment: @synaptik : If you use `reserve` properly, anyone who suggests raw pointers are faster than `std::vector<>` in release mode are just spouting FUD.

Comment: @SteveHoward Your statement should read *This isn't a direct answer but I think in C++ this kind of comment should be encouraged as well.*

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in any of the `record...` methods that bounds checks the age. So, if age happens to be greater than `260` or less than `0` in your example, you will write past the bounds of either `RP` or `Biopsy` or `PSA`. That leads directly to a "double free or corruption" error.

Comment: Good point, however I know that age doesn't happen to exceed its bounds.  For example, if I simply comment out the delete statement, the program runs without error.  (And, yes, I'm talking about using precisely the same random number stream.)

Comment: @synaptik, just because it doesn't throw an error does not mean it doesn't have one. It just means you didn't trigger any error catching code. Track `numDecisionEpochs` as an additional member of `Patient` and see if you ever pass in `age<0 || age>=numDecisionEpochs`.

Comment: you're quite right!  I should have said that rather than being free from error, it at least doesn't throw throw the double free error.  I will double-check though, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Ah-hah!  You are absolutely right!  I forgot that age needed to be shifted before indexing into the arrays.  It was, in fact, pointing out of range.  Thanks for that--forgive my stubbornness :)